# Angular Unit Testing Directive for Input Restriction

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs-directive, karma-jasmine

I have a directive with restricts user from Inputting special characters. Trying to write a unit test that validates to make sure user is not able to input special characters.

Below I am trying to simulate keydown event when user enters A@ - and need to test only A was allowed to be entered. Looks like the input is not getting updated with these values via events. console.log(input.value) prints empty string. The only way I can set the value is input.value but in that case I am able to set special characters as well which is not what I want.

Anyway to reflect user input and validate to make sure special character was not allowed?

```
    it('should not allow special chars', () => {
        component.regexInput = '[a-zA-Z0-9\-\_ ]{1,25}';
        fixture.detectChanges();
        const input = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('input');
        const event = new KeyboardEvent("keydown", {
            "key": "A"
        });
        input.dispatchEvent(event);
        fixture.detectChanges();
        const event2 = new KeyboardEvent("keydown", {
            "key": "@"
        });
        input.dispatchEvent(event2);
        fixture.detectChanges();
        console.log(input.value);
        expect(input.value).toEqual('A');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you still have the old `input` selected.

Try:

```
it('should not allow special chars', async () => {
        component.regexInput = '[a-zA-Z0-9\-\_ ]{1,25}';
        fixture.detectChanges();
        const input = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('input');
        const event = new KeyboardEvent("keydown", {
            "key": "A"
        });
        input.dispatchEvent(event);
        fixture.detectChanges();
        const event2 = new KeyboardEvent("keydown", {
            "key": "@"
        });
        input.dispatchEvent(event2);
        fixture.detectChanges();
        await fixture.whenStable();
        const newInput = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('input'); // grab a new reference here
        console.log(newInput.value);
        expect(newInput.value).toEqual('A');
    });
```

The `async` and `await fixture.whenStable()` can be optional. First try to do it without those and see if it works. If it doesn't, add `async` and `fixture.whenStable()` because I remember some aspects of Angular forms are asynchronous.